# Selenium MSEdge - open the IE mode in Edge without DevToolsActivePort error being thrown

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

MSEdgeDriver and browser version used 88.0.705.63 (64 bit).

Works when provided with edge options.addArguments("--headless") or with-remote-debugging-port ; but when we remove -remote-debugging-port,DevToolsActivePort error is thrown as shwon below.

With  -remote-debugging-port, the site is not opened with Internet Explorer mode. Is there any way we can open the IE mode in Edge and not get DevToolsActivePort error

```
Message: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'A036T0L6347NRVX', ip: '10.227.221.75', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: driver.version: EdgeDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF6D6D0AF92+241554]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6D747CA88+2173368]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6D749FAC8+2316792]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6D7499BC9+2292473]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6D74CB760+2496144]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6D74C7A5F+2480527]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6D74A550A+2339898]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6D74A614B+2343035]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF6D6CE2D01+77057]
```

Comment: There's no way to enable IE mode in Edge using Selenium WebDriver with Java till now. Even if you're not using `-remote-debugging-port`, it will still show "Turn off remote debugging to open this site in IE mode otherwise it might not work as expected". If you're using C#, you can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63539044/how-to-enable-ie-mode-in-chromium-edge-browser-in-selenium-c) to enable IE mode in Edge using Selenium.